# Can a .jar file to be exexcuted under Windows have more than one main method?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

we have a big project with many classes (~100) and in some there are main methods.

Building a runnable .jar-File to be executed under a WinXP environment fails; we have the idea that maybe it is because there is not only one but many main-methods in our project?!

So I read some about it and as fas as I got it, a .jar can contain more than 1 main-method; they would be called like this:

```
 java -classpath myJarFile.jar A
 java -classpath myJarFile.jar B
 java -classpath myJarFile.jar C
```

where A,B and C have their own main methods (see http://www.coderanch.com/t/373658/java/java/Executing-main-methods-jar-file)

**My question is: Does having more than one main method affect the problem-free running on Windows ?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"Building a runnable .jar-File to be executed under a WinXP environment fails."* Fails *how*? With what error or unexpected result?

Answer (score 2):

You've said you're making a *runnable* jar file, but your examples (`java -classpath myJarFile.jar A`) aren't using it as a *runnable* jar; they're just using it as a jar. You're specifying what class to run on the `java` command-line. That should work just fine.

Re *runnable* jars: The point of runnable jars is that you don't have to start them with the `java` command directly; you just double-click the jar in a file explorer, make it the target of a shortcut, etc., and the `java` tool is run automatically (via file association), using the jar's *startup class*, which is specified in the manifest you used when creating the runnable jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Startup
```

In that example, `Startup` is the startup class for the runnable jar.

You could make the jar a runnable jar (e.g., pick a default class to run the `main` from and make it the startup) and still allow the jar to be run via the `java` tool choosing another class. That's fine.

Answer (score 1):

No - the main method is just the entry point for the program.

Comment: Which for a runnable jar is indicated in the manifest file. You can still have one for each class if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

For executing the application Main method is just like door for entire application. But you can add some other class as well which is have there individual main methods but entry main method should all ways be one.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a problem if you are able to control the invocation of your program (as opposed to this being a dropin/plugin, for example).

Answer (score 0):

> Does having more than one main method affect the problem-free running on Windows ?

It will if you try to do `java -jar myJarFile.jar`. The jar manifest allows you to optionally specify no more than one main class.

If you want  have multiple main methods you need to use following syntax only

```
java -classpath myJarFile.jar  A
```